# Parallel-For loops and consistency

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, pass-by-reference

I'm working an Euler problem with an outer and inner loop.  The outer loop contains the value being checked, the inner loop controls how many test iterations pass, in this case looking for Lychrel numbers.

The outer loop works in parallel just fine, but the inner loop is extremely inconsistent.  You can see from my commented out lines that I've tried a `List<T>` and used `lock`ing, as well as using `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.  My initial implementation used a bool set to true (that the number IS a Lychrel number) which would get set to false if proven otherwise after n-iterations.  It would then just count the number of collected Lychrel numbers. The bool operation wasn't working so well, jumping out of the inner loop (even with a `lock`). I even tried to implement a threadsafe boolean, but so far nothing has kept the inner loop consistent.  At this point it's become a learning exercise.  I'm generally familiar with threading, and use it fairly regularly even with collections, but this one stumps me as to the root cause of the problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        BigInteger answer = 0;
        List<long> lychrels = new List<long>();
        ConcurrentQueue<long> CQlychrels = new ConcurrentQueue<long>();
        long maxValue = 10000;
        long maxIterations = 50;


        sw.Start();
        //for (int i = 1; i < maxValue; i++)
        Parallel.For(1, maxValue, i =>
        {
            BigInteger workingValue = i;
            //bool lychrel = true;

            //for (int w = 1; w < maxIterations; w++)
            Parallel.For(1, maxIterations, (w, loopstate) =>
            {
                workingValue = workingValue.LychrelAdd();
                if (workingValue.ToString().Length > 1)
                    if (IsPalindrome(workingValue))
                    {
                        //lychrel = false;
                        CQlychrels.Enqueue(i);
                        //lock (lychrels)
                            //lychrels.Add(i);
                        loopstate.Break();

                        //break;
                    }
            });

            //if (!lychrel)
                //lock (lychrels)
                    //lychrels.Add(i);
        });

        answer = maxValue - CQlychrels.Count();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + answer);
        Console.WriteLine("Found in " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks.");
        Console.WriteLine("Found in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms.");

        while (Console.ReadKey() == null)
        { }

        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

`BigInteger.LychrelAdd()` just takes the value and a mirror of it's value and adds them together.

I suspect, perhaps, that either that or `IsPalindrome()` not being threadsafe may be the cause?  Setting `workingValue` outside of that loop and working on it inside?  Something to do with `BigInteger` being a reference value and that reference changing?

Comment: This: `workingValue = workingValue.LychrelAdd();`. Whatever this is, you've got multiple threads operating on this and replacing the reference. This will predictably behave unpredictably. Whether it's via a `lock` or something else, this needs to become atomic. Another solution is to keep a local copy within each loop so that there's less locking, and then after the loop is done update the shared value from the result of the loop.

Comment: @ScottHannen gah, that seems obvious now.

Comment: I would get ride from the parallelism in the inner loop altogether. The outer `Parallel.For` should be enough to keep all the processors/cores of your machine busy, unless you have thousands of them, which is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - that's a really good point. I'd start by writing this as simple as possible using a separate class (not in the console.) Verify it with a unit test, not by reading the console output. That will allow you to test using different input parameters without having to modify your code. Once your tests pass, then you can introduce the parallelism. Unit tests are the best thing since wrapped bread.

Comment: @ScottHannen it was originally written without parallelism. Then I added it for the outer. Then tried adding it for just the inner and it was already problematic. But the reference is almost certainly the cause.